# Time optimization of large, filtered table for both read and write

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

Currently I am working on a large JAVA application connected with a JavaScript framework frontend and a SQL Server database. The frontend displays huge, paginated table with 200 columns of various types and few million rows. Moreover, every single column has it's own filter, like in Excel's table.

Users need to read, filter and modify data quickly. Our research shown that the bottleneck is on the database query- this table is physically located on the SQL Server database, and it is not indexed. It takes unacceptable amount of time to fetch rows or list of possible values for the filter's dropdowns.

We were thinking about adding simple, default indices for every single column, but they jeopardize updating and adding rows; not only by the users, but also by the cron job that inserts new bulk of data four times a day.

I am asking here instead of on dba.stackexchange.com because I suspect the pattern for overcoming such difficulties may involve JAVA application, maybe some kind of cache in spring?

Comment: This is a generic challenge for dynamic searches. 

See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html for a detailed discussion of solutions and optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

kowalt, ideas from the seen-it cheap seats...

First, does the Javascript framework create filter-able list based upon what is rendered; meaning, does it fetch all possible values of a column filter from the database or is it just of what's dished out in that pages' HTML content?  If it's the latter, then recognize the limits of framework for filtering if there is no call back to the database via the application - therefore the Javascript performance is the focal point (up until a sort-by or where-by query is performed).

Second, is it possible to have a presentation data source separate from the transnational (x4/day) source?  You may have architectural options with separate replicated source for indexing on the most probable columns (e.g. optimizing some, but not all) apart from dragging down the transnational source.  The indexing and refreshing of indexes could be scoped and run as a (say, daily) process by a DB dev.

Third, is is possible to feed the Javascript from the Java application the necessary metadata for the filtering dropdowns from a separate thread, especially if the range of possible entries isn't likely to change significantly.  This may help any full(HTML) table scans attempted on the client side browser.

Forth (low-probability), maybe explore running the database in an in-memory process.  This could be raw solution if infrastructure is no expense.

Good luck.

Comment: Javascript is not culprit here- as in your first suggestion, it fetch all possible values of a column filter from the database, and the generated SQL query takes very long on the DB.